# ng-init function not retrieving directly on load from Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ng-init

I have this code to retrieve data from Firebase

```
.controller('CouCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

      $scope.selectcc = function () 
        {

        var depid = $stateParams.did;
        var ccref = firebase.database().ref('/Course/').orderByChild('D_id').equalTo(depid);
                ccref.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
                $scope.courses = snapshot.val();  
                }); 
        }  
    })
```

and this is my html code

```
<ion-view class="bk">
 <ion-content ng-init="selectcc()">

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item  ng-repeat="e in courses" href="#/tab/results/{{e.CC_id}}">
         {{e.CC_id}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

 </ion-content >
</ion-view>
```

the code is working correct, but I should back then return again to the page to show the ion-list. "its not showing directly on load the page

Answer (score 2):

## Firebase promises are not AngularJS promises

Promises returned by the firebase API are not integrated with the AngularJS framework.

Use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to create an AngularJS promise from a firebase promise:

```
$scope.selectcc = function () {
    var depid = $stateParams.did;
    var ccref = firebase.database().ref('/Course/').orderByChild('D_id').equalTo(depid);
    //USE $q.when
    $q.when(ccref.once('value')).then(function (snapshot) {
        $scope.courses = snapshot.val();  
    }); 
}
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The firebase promise needs to be converted to an AngularJS promise to bring the event into the AngularJS execution context.

> ### $q.when(value)
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)